# Model.all and Model.find(id): can I do this with one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two models: Building and Apartment.  Building has_many :apartments and Apartment has_many :buildings.  In the Apartment index, I want to list all buildings, so that users can filter the apartments by which building they are in.  Sometimes, however, I want to also pull one specific apartment -- if the apartment id has already been given.  Right now, in apartments#index, I have:

def index

```
@buildings = Buildings.all

    if params[:building_id] # the apartments resource is nested in the building resource route.
        @building = Building.find(params[:building_id])
    end

end
```

Is there a better way to do this, without running two queries?

Answer (score 0):

well alternative may be.

```
@buildings = Building.all

    if params[:building_id] 
        @building = @buildings.select{|b| b.id == params[:building_id}.first
    end

end
```

but this is poor performance if the collection is really big, so stay with 2 db calls.

Answer (score 0):

The `detect` method searches an enumerable for an object matching the block, for example

```
building = buildings.detect {|b| b.id == params[:building_id].to_i}
```

This will be linear in the amount of buildings to search, although if the amount of buildings is small enough that you are loading them all anyway this might not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby's Array#select to pick the item you want from the fetched array.

```
def index
  @buildings = Buildings.all
  if params[:building_id] 
    @building = @buildings.select({|building| building.id == params[:building_id]}).first
  end
end
```